# Pycharm color scheme is not working even after change from settings

Tags: python, pycharm

This is now really annoying to me. I am not able to change pycharm code font color even after changing from seeting> appearance . Only back ground changes. but code font color doesn't change. restarted pycharm. but no help. please help.

[my current setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XW93W.png)

[No change is reflected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCums.png)

Answer (score 0):

`app.py` is associated with `text` file type, that's why all the highlighting is missing. Try to remove `app.py` from **Settings | Editor | File Types | Registered File Types | Text | Registered Patterns**:

[image]